# Classifying coordinates on land/on water using QGIS very slow processing issue

Tags: qgis-processing, classification, select-by-location

I'm very new to QGIS. I have a problem related to the "select by location" tool of QGIS.

I have loaded 10 different layers into my map containing data of waters (rivers, canals etc.). Now, I want to classify my own data, consisting of ID's with latitude/longitude, as "on land" or "on water". I have chosen the intersect function of QGIS to solve this problem. However, my data contains millions of datapoints which causes the process to be very slow. I have checked the "Use only selected features" checkbox, and the plan is to repeat this step for every single layer. The first layer is "creating a new selection", the next layers should be "add to current selection". Now, the problem is that it takes more than 1 hour for the first layer already. Is there a way to speed up the process? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Tile your "Godzilla" polygon data by intersecting them with  a regular grid.  See [ArcGIS Blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/dicing-godzillas-features-with-too-many-vertices/) and [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/people/vangelo-esristaff/blog/2014/09/15/partitioning-large-geometries-to-improve-query-performance)

Comment: If the Water area is much smaller than Land, just Intersect with Water. If the return is Null, it is Land.

Comment: The return will be Null/None if the point is outside the data extent @klewis. Vince has the right idea *but* if that doesn't speed up enough try using the regular grid you have intersected with your data and populate a field using select by location with values for all land, all water or a mix of water and land, first check against the fishnet and see if there is a mix of land and water and only then progress to testing against the *diced* polygons. This will speed processing as the fishnet is less complicated polygons and should select much quicker then use full select for points in doubt.

Comment: Thank your for your suggestions. The process I mentioned earlier, is already focusing on intersecting only with the water, as suggested by @klewis . This process takes too much time.

Comment: @MichaelStimson could you describe how that exactly works? I'm new to QGIS, so I do not know what steps to take. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have a Spatial Index on all your data.

Comment: Try the suggestion from Vince first, dicing the polygons using a fishnet grid, with spatial indices as klewis suggests; the method I have outlined is for emulating the function of a spatial index on datasets that do not support spatial indexing (like CAD). The size of the fishnet grid cells is crucial, too large and the polygons will be very complex, too small and there will be too many geometries to check, either way there will be no performance gain. I would suggest a fishnet of no less than 1% and no more than 5% of the data extent.